# convert from https to http seo implications

Tags: http, https, seo

I'm thinking of converting from https to http (major parts of the site will be http, but secure parts will be https). what are the seo implications when Google already lists the https version as #4 when I search for the site? What can I do to mitigate these consequences?

Comment: If you're paying someone for SEO, you can probably afford using https.  IMHO, SEO is snake oil, and very temporary at best, at worst, if detected, the search engine ranks you down for attempting SEO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions now belong on [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to http should not have any effect on your rankings as it does not have anything to do with the content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to switch from https to http? https is more secure, has no negativ impacts for the customer and google explicitly encourage webmasters to use https for a "safer" web.

If you still want to migrate from http to https you should make sure, that your https version redirects to the http version with an 301 (moved permanently) header to prevent duplicate content (same page, same content, different urls)